# Adding data from a file to a list for sorting

Tags: python

my text file contains some integer values like below:

```
100
200
300
400
500
600
700
800
900
1000
```

i want to add them to a list, then sort them and print the sorted list. i tried something like:

```
file = open("sample.txt","r")
list1 = []

for line in range(1,11):
    data = file.readline(line)
    list1.append(data)

sortedlist = list1.sort(key=int)
print sortedlist
file.close()
```

but i got an error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "o_2.py", line 8, in <module>
    sortedlist = list1.sort(key=int)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

also when i checked the list without sorting it was something like:

```
['1', '00', '\n', '200\n', '300\n', '400\n', '500\n', '600\n', '700\n', '800\n']
```

i am actually very new to python. so if anybody could explain the whole case with solution it would be very helpful for me. thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried making `list1` a numpy array and then sort it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading the list wrong; [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline) does not take the line number, but the **maximum number of characters per line**:

> `file.readline([size])`
>
> Read one entire line from the file. A trailing newline character is kept in the string (but may be absent when a file ends
>   with an incomplete line). [6] **If the size argument is present and
>   non-negative, it is a maximum byte count (including the trailing
>   newline) and an incomplete line may be returned.** When size is not 0,
>   an empty string is returned only when EOF is encountered immediately.

Your code would work if you just did `file.readline()`:

```
for line in range(1,11):
    data = file.readline()
    list1.append(data)
```

The current code tries to read only 1, 2 and 3 characters of the *first* line, which results in `'1'`, `'00'` and the `'\n'` newline being read separately, followed by max 4 characters of line 2 (`'200\n'`) etc.

---

However it is not very pythonic either; I would write it as:

```
with open("sample.txt") as file:
     list1 = [ int(line) for line in file ]

sortedlist = list1.sort()
print sortedlist
```

`with` automatically closes the file at the end of indented block. `for` loop for a file automatically iterates over its lines; `[ expression for var in iterable ]` is a list comprehension, that is a shorter way of doing:

```
result = []
for var in iterable:
    result.append(expression)
```

Or as Jon Clements suggested, if you really want to sort the lines by their numerical value, but keeping them as string:

```
with open('sample.txt') as file:
    list1 = list(file)  # all lines as a list
    print sorted(list1, key=int)
```

Comment: The `line.strip()` is redundant for stuff being passed to `int` - it already does stripping... Also, this means the OPs list ends up as `int`s... who knows - they may still want strings... Look almost like the entire code required (after the `with`) could be: `print sorted(file, key=int)`

Answer (score -1):

Your  code not removes spaces and newlines.

Import re
   txt=open('file').read()
   List=Re.findall('\d ',txt)
   now list contain all numbers all other symbols will skipped